# How to manage prefix in Symfony (3.0) with bundle KnpMenu

Tags: php, symfony, knpmenubundle, knpmenu

I was struggling to add prefix in my route with KnpMenu on Symfony 3.0, my prefix being the language ISO initials.

I was getting an error message similar to that:
**Some mandatory parameters are missing ("_locale") to generate a URL for route "home"**

Found a solution, I share it with you:

In my routing file I had:

```
#[my_project]\app\config\routing.yml    
my_app:
      resource: "@MyBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
      prefix: /{_locale}
      requirements:
        _locale: fr|en
```

In my sub routing file:

```
#[my_project]\src\MyBundle\Resources\config\routing.yml    
home:
  path: /home
  defaults: {_controller:MyBundle:Home:index}
```

I implemented the menu as explained in the doc (see: https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenu)

```
  #[my_project]\MyBundle\Menu\Builder.php
  namespace MyBundle\Menu;

  use Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface;
  use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
  use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareTrait;

  class Builder implements ContainerAwareInterface{


      use ContainerAwareTrait;

      public function mainMenu(FactoryInterface $factory, array $options){


            $menu = $factory->createItem('root');

            $logger = $GLOBALS['kernel']->getContainer()->get('logger');
            $logger->info('in mainMenu');

            $session = $this->container->get('session');
            $locale = $session->get('_locale');

            $routeParameters = array('_locale'=>$locale);

            $menu->addChild('home', array('routeParameters' =>  $routeParameters,'route' => 'home'));

            return $menu;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please keep questions as questions and answers as answers. Each should stand on its own. I have edited your question/answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll follow your advise in the future @k0pernikus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to **implement the routeParameters array inside the array parameter required by the method addChild()**:
$menu->addChild('home', array(**'routeParameters' =>  $routeParameters**,'route' => 'home'));